# Redshift: Are simple views as performant as tables?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, view, amazon-redshift

How does Redshift process queries against a view that is simply a `create view view_name as select * from table`? Does it treat queries against this view any differently than queries against the underlying table?

Which of these would perform best/worst? Are there any of these that would destroy my performance?

```
select
  *
from
  fact_table;
```

```
create view fact_view as
select
  *
from
  fact_table;

select
  *
from
  fact_view;
```

Does anything change when we add inner joins?

```
create view fact_view as
select
  *
from
  fact_table;

create view dim_view as
select
  *
from
  dim_table;

select
  *
from
  fact_table f
  join dim_table d
  on f.key = d.key;

select
  *
from
  fact_view f
  join dim_view d
  on f.key = d.key;
```

And finally, left joins:

```
create view fact_view as
select
  *
from
  fact_table;

create view dim_view as
select
  *
from
  dim_table;

select
  *
from
  fact_table f
  left join dim_table d
  on f.key = d.key;

select
  *
from
  fact_view f
  left join dim_view d
  on f.key = d.key;
```

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: there shouldn't be that much difference, but see if EPLAIN and ANALYse helps you see any difference